# Rails: Wrong hostname for url helpers in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

Url helpers (e.g root_url) returns a different hostname in the app controllers vs rspec examples.
I have successfully been able to set the domain for url helpers in my rails app like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def default_url_options
    {host: "foo.com", only_path: false}
  end
end
```

For example, root_url outputs "http://foo.com/" within the application but "http://example.com" in my request specs. What is the recommended way to apply those url options globally in rails 3.2 so that they affect my specs?
The url options do not need to be dynamic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Feature specs, host! has been deprecated. Add these to your rspec_helper.rb:

```
# Configure Capybara expected host
Capybara.app_host = 'http://lvh.me:3000'

# Configure actual routes host during test
before(:each) do
  if respond_to?(:default_url_options)
    default_url_options[:host] = 'http://lvh.me:3000'
  end
end
```

Comment: FYI, this fails if the test is not controller/request/feature. A Helper spec, for example, fails with `undefined local variable or method default_url_options'`.

Comment: I put the 'if respond_to? .... default_url_options[:host] ... end` bit into a `before(:each)` block in spec_helper.rb and that was effective.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to Dan's answer it would look something like this in spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # other config options
  config.before(:each) do
    host! "localhost:3000"
  end
end
```

Comment: Does not work for me in spec_helper: NoMethodError: undefined method `host!'. I'm using Rspec 3.2.

Comment: Still works on 2022 with rspec 3.10, rails 6.1.4, and ruby 3.0.1

Answer (score 2):

You can set the host in a before block in your test in rspec:

```
    before :each do
      host! 'hostgoeshere.com'
    end
```

If you want to set it globally you could put something your spec_helper.rb file.

Comment: could you be more specific about what the "something" might be?

Answer (score 1):

I tried many variations of `@request.host`, `host!`, and `post path, args, {'SERVER_NAME' => my_secret_domain}` without success, both as controller tests and feature tests.  Very aggravating, as so many others reported success with those approaches.

The solution for me was:

```
request.headers["SERVER_NAME"] = my_secret_domain
post path, args
```

I'm running ruby 2.1.5p273, rspec 3.1.7 and Rails 4.2.0