# rpsec-rails with apartment Gem and Grape cannot set host with subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rspec-rails, ruby-grape

I am using **Rails 4.2.6, Ruby 2.2.1, rspec-rails 3.4.2, Grape 0.16.2**, **grape_token_auth 0.1.0**. I installed **apartment gem (1.0.2)** for multitenancy and trying to write rspec tests for grape requests.

But I am getting the **following error** from rspec-rails response method every time irrespective of whatever solutions I tried.

```
@buf=["<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Apartment::TenantNotFound at /content/api/v1/questions</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n
```

The request is taking the host as '**www.example.com**' all time. I tried so many solutions by googling it. But nothing works. you can see that in spec where I commented these lines. I want the url as 'http://g_m.lvh.me:3000' with the subdomain 'g_m'.

I tried this one:
https://github.com/influitive/apartment/wiki/Testing-Your-Application
But not works. I don't know why.

I tried this, but not working:
[Rails: Wrong hostname for url helpers in rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521201/rails-wrong-hostname-for-url-helpers-in-rspec)

and tried to set the host by:

```
host! "g_m.lvh.me:3000"
@request.host = 'g_m.lvh.me:3000'
request.host = 'g_m.lvh.me:3000'
```

Nothing works!

I created a test case like the following grape link says:
https://github.com/dblock/grape/commit/99bf4b44c511541c0e10f4506bf34ae9abcccd75

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ContentManager::QuestionAPI, :type => :request do
  #before(:each) { Apartment::Tenant.switch!("g_m")  }
  #after(:each) { Apartment::Tenant.switch!("public")  }

  #before(:each) do
   #begin
       #client = FactoryGirl.create(:client, title: 'Sample title',    subdomain: 'g_m')
   #rescue
     #client = Client.create!(title: 'Sample title',   subdomain: 'g_m')
   #end

   #default_url_options[:host] = 'http://g_m.lvh.me:3000'
   # request.host = "#{'g_m'}.lvh.me"
   #end
 #end

 #before(:each) do
 #  if respond_to?(:default_url_options)
 #    default_url_options[:host] = 'http://g_m.lvh.me:3000'
 #  end
 #end

  describe "GET /content/api/v1/questions" do
    it "returns an empty array of questions" do
    get "/content/api/v1/questions"
    #puts "response.inspect: #{response.inspect}"
    response.status.should == 200
    JSON.parse(response.body).should == []
   end
 end
end
```

My configurations:

```
in spec/rails_helper.rb

config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, type: :request, file_path: /spec\/requests/
```

All time this request sent by rspec-rails with

```
url: '/content/api/v1/questions'
host: 'www.example.com'
```

My test result shows:

```
$ rspec spec/requests/

F

Failures:

1) ContentManager::QuestionAPI GET /content/api/v1/questions returns an empty array of questions
  Failure/Error: response.status.should == 200

   expected: 200
        got: 500 (using ==)
 # ./spec/requests/question_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Deprecation Warnings:

Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should` syntax without      explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax     or explicitly enable `:should` with `config.expect_with(:rspec) { |c| c.syntax = :should }` instead. Called from /home/vagrant/gauge-slcsl/spec/requests/question_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'.


If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
`config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.

1 deprecation warning total

Finished in 6.19 seconds (files took 1.93 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/question_spec.rb:26 # ContentManager::QuestionAPI GET /content/api/v1/questions returns an empty array of questions

abhi@ubuntu-trusty-64:~/my-app$
```

If anyone knows about the error and what I am doing wrong here, please reply/answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because of, we have to say the apartment subdomain configuration that just **exclude the 'www' word considering as a sub domain**.

Add the following:

```
# config/initializers/apartment/subdomain_exclusions.rb
Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain.excluded_subdomains = ['www']
```

I was using the **better_errors** gem in my development and test environment. This causes the rspec output as an better error generated html codes and difficult to understand the rspec failure reason.

I removed better errors from 'test' environment and I got the clue of this error where we have to exclude the 'www' considering as a subdomain.